# Disable sound made on mute keypress in Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4

With a Galaxy S4 / Jelly Bean OS, every time I press the mute button the phone emits a sound that's audible to other parties. Can this be disabled? I tried disabling all keyboard sounds in the Ringtones and keypad tones menu, but that didn't seem to help. What else can I try?

Comment: What's a mute button? Is that the one when you long-press the power button, and click the Mute icon?

Comment: I think he talks about the "micro" button (for voice typing)

Comment: On the call screen / keypad there are six buttons. Add call, Hide, End call, Speaker, Mute and Headset. This mute button is the button I'm concerned with.

Comment: Can you hear the sound, or only them?

Comment: I guess the "mute" button Derek's talking about is the one to mute the mike. But as geffchang asked: Do those "other parties" the sound is "audible to" include the "other end of the line", i.e. the ones you talk to on the phone?

Comment: Yes, both I and the other parties can hear the sound.